# What are "sugoi kawaii desu!!!!!11" guys/girls?

Tags: culture, meme

So i found this image highlighting the difference between an Otaku and a Weeaboo

[image: Otaku VS Weeaboo]

the 7th point says

> Enjoys the "sugoi kawaii desu!!!!!11" guys/girls

my understanding of japanese (which isn't impressive, still learning) is that:

- **kawaii** = cute,
- **sugoi** is like extreme or in the extreme
- **desu** = yes (going by Suiseiseki's translation of "desu desu" being "yes yes")

and going by the first point i could assume it actually says

> Enjoys the "Extremely Cute Yes!!!!!11" guys/girls

But what are "sugoi kawaii desu!!!!!11" guys/girls?

Comment: desu can be used like "is". so i think it would translate to guys or girls who are extremely cute.

Comment: I think it is what it is. Compared to the Otaku-side where they enjoy the whole element of the anime, weeaboos only watch the anime to see their idol: cute/handsome characters.

Comment: i thought it was a meme ...

Comment: issa meme issa trap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The fourth point :

> will often use Japanese words like "**Kawaii**" to sound "**cool**"

From [***A list of commonly used weeaboo words for normal people***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2AX1.jpg) :

> Weeaboos are people who think they know Japanese, but they really only know a few words/phrases and know jack about syntax and grammar.
>
> kawaii = cute
> desu = lit. "it is" but weebs use it to make sentences sound cute/authentic

It suggest that a Weeaboo is someone who knows only few words and dont know correct meaning,

So the phrase `sugoi kawaii desu!!!!!11` doesn't have a correct meaning.

What the mean could be as [Aki Tanaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2516/aki-tanaka) said in the comments

> I think it is what it is. Compared to the Otaku-side where they enjoy the whole element of the anime, weeaboos only watch the anime to see their idol: cute/handsome characters.

It could be read as "Enjoys the Extremely Cute guys/girls"